# how to access google cloud datalab from a different computer

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I had a cloud datalab account and I suddenly I faced some issues to connect to my datalab from my computer so how can I access my cloud datalab from a different computer.

Answer (score 2):

The way you connect to your Datalab instance should be the same regardless of which computer you are connecting from.

The prerequisites are installing the Cloud SDK, authenticating to `gcloud`, and configuring the project and zone in `gcloud`. After that, the exact same command should work on your other computer.